# Versioning history for web part 

Tags: 2007

can we get versioning history for web pat and site or any other related information like last modified,modified by for web part and site in moss 2007.

kindly let me know if there is any way to find it in moss 2007.

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this information isn't recorded. List Items are versioned, web parts are not.

You can get the [LastItemModifiedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) for a site through code.

Comment: Irellevant for your case, but sp2010 Web parts is versioned